# Training predefined NER model of Spacy, with custom data, need idea about compound factor, batch size and loss values

Tags: python, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train spacy NER model, i have data of about 2600 paragraphs length of paragraph range from 200 to 800 words each. I have to add Two new entity labels, PRODUCT and SPECIFICATION. Is it, this approach is good to train in case no any best alternative to do so? if it is ok, to go with then can anyone suggest me the appropriate values of Compounding factor and batch size and while training, Losses value should range in, any idea? as of if now i am getting my losses value ranging from 400-5.

```
def main(model=None, new_model_name='product_details_parser', 
output_dir=Path('/xyz_path/'), n_iter=20):
"""Set up the pipeline and entity recognizer, and train the new
 entity."""
    if model is not None:
        nlp = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
        print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # create blank Language class
        print("Created blank 'en' model")
    # Add entity recognizer to model if it's not in the pipeline
    # nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner)
    # otherwise, get it, so we can add labels to it
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')
    ner.add_label(LABEL)   # add new entity label to entity recognizer
    if model is None:
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    else:
        # Note that 'begin_training' initializes the models, so it'll zero out
        # existing entity types.
        optimizer = nlp.entity.create_optimizer()

     # get names of other pipes to disable them during training
     other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
     with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        for itn in range(n_iter):
            random.shuffle(ret_data)
            losses = {}
            # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
            batches = minibatch(ret_data, size=compounding(1., 32., 1.001))
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35,losses=losses)
            print('Losses', losses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plac.call(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this type of traning,you can begin with simple training method (https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-simple-style). This simple method might take sometime when compared to your method,but will yeild better results.